# How can I take the HTML/data from a Google Document and restyle it with CSS?

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, google-docs, css

I have a list in a Google Document that I would like to restlye with CSS. Unfortunately Google Docs no longer allows using CSS/HTML styling within the app itself. What would I need to do to get information from a Google Document and turn the data into a standalone site styled with my own CSS?n Would it involve using a script of some sort? Scraping the info somehow with Regex? Perhaps the Google Drive API would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get the content of a document using Google Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app 
and generate html output 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/